# Querying Access from VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am currently trying to write a query in `VBA` to obtain data in `Access`. For the string `SQL`, everything works except for the WHERE clause and I am not sure how to write it syntax wise. I am getting a

> Run-Time error 3075 - Syntax error (missing operator) in query
>   expression.

Below is my code:

```
Sub ImportFromAccess_Size()

    database_file_path = Range("Database_File_Path").Value

    Dim DbLoc As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim xlbook As Workbook
    Dim xlsheet As Worksheet
    Dim recCount As Long
    Dim SQL As String

    DbLoc = database_file_path

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set xlbook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set xlsheet = Sheets("Simulation Input Data") 

    Application.StatusBar = "Connecting to an external database..."
    'Application.Cursor = xlWait

    tool_file_path = Range("Tool_File_Path").Value
    database_file_path = Range("Database_File_Path").Value
    size_system = Range("Size_System").Value

    Set db = OpenDatabase(DbLoc)
    'Set db = OpenDatabase(database_file_path)

    SQL = "SELECT SCHED_SURGERY_DATETIME "
    SQL = SQL & "FROM Raw_Data "
    SQL = SQL & "ORDER BY SCHED_SURGERY_DATETIME "
    SQL = SQL & "WHERE [PROCEDURE_NM_WID] = (" & size_system & ")"

    Sheets("Simulation Input Data").Activate

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
    xlsheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

End Sub
```

Comment: Is [PROCEDURE_NM_WID] text, number, date, other?

Comment: It is a text. and size_system is a string. Raw_Data is the table where the information is stored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the text string criteria in single quotes (aka 'ticks')

```
SQL = "SELECT [SCHED_SURGERY_DATETIME] "
SQL = SQL & "FROM Raw_Data "
SQL = SQL & "WHERE [PROCEDURE_NM_WID] = '" & size_system & "' "
SQL = SQL & "ORDER BY [SCHED_SURGERY_DATETIME];"
```